# How can I set an action work flow as async?

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow, action, dynamics-crm-2016

I have created an ACTION workflow, and it's synchronous as default, Can I change it to asynchronous and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain the options we have.

1. You can have a custom Action and that can be invoked from an Asynchronous workflow. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/invoke-custom-actions-workflow-dialog?view=op-9-1)
2. You can register an Asynchronous plugin step to execute on this Custom Action message. [Read more](https://blog.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/dominicjarvis/2017/09/18/how-to-trigger-plugins-on-custom-messages-using-actions-in-dynamics-365)